# Back to the same view in the same line after insert or delete. Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am new in laravel and php. I write a code for delete and insert functions after the function done .. I need to back to the same view so the user can delete or insert again.
I try this code for delete function:

```
function deleF(Request $request)
    {
      $filename=$request->input('filename');
      DB::table('files')->where(['id'=>$filename])->delete();
      return redirect()->back()->with('alert','deleted');
    }
```

But I have this error:

> Undefined variable: courseN

Note: courseN this variable I used it before this function in a view.

update:
this is the part of the view which contains $courseN:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      @foreach  ($courseN as $cou)
      <li>{{$cou->enname}}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Comment: show us the code on on how you show your view

Comment: It should work properly. Your error is not related to that function.

Comment: Note:

login function .. sends courseN variable to the view and opens the view.

in the view .. I call deleF function then I need to return to the view after that called line

Comment: Your sending it via POST method?

Comment: yes it is post method

Comment: You have to recover all view variables when you redirect back. Provide more code please. What is the $courseN in the view?

Comment: I use this line ..  return redirect()->back()->with('courseN',$courseN); but is not working

Comment: You cannot pass back the data since it is POST method. Read my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the previous view that you want to get back to is accessible via POST or other method other than GET. When you are using the back() method. You are redirecting back to your page via GET method. So passing back the data is not a solution here.

You only have two options

- You should change the method of your previous page into `GET` so you
  can easily get back to anytime you want.
- or delete the item via AJAX so the page don't need to refresh.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: I have to use post function

Comment: The issue here is not about the missing variable. It is about how you access the page. As you've said, you can only access the prev page via POST method and you are tying to go back using the back() method which can only give you `GET` request. You should use AJAX to delete data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell.. the above function works just fine. but the view is loaded without the `courseN` variable and therefor you have the error

Try to change your function so it passes the `courseN` variable to your view.

For example something like this:

```
function deleF(Request $request)
    {
      $filename=$request->input('filename');
      DB::table('files')->where(['id'=>$filename])->delete();

      $courseN = 'something it has to be'

      return redirect()->back()->with('courseN',$courseN);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
function deleF(Request $request)
    {
      $filename=$request->input('filename');
      DB::table('files')->where(['id'=>$filename])->delete();

      $courseN = 'false';

      return redirect()->back()->with('courseN',$courseN);
    }
```

Hope this work for you !!!